# How to set up Optional MFA with AWS Cognito AmplifyAuthenticator?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, multi-factor-authentication, totp

If I set a cognito pool to `require` MFA (TOTP) my implementation on the client side with `AmplifyAuthenticator` from `@aws-amplify/ui-react` works just fine automatically.

But if I create a cognito pool where MFA is `optional`, there is no automatic option for the user to opt into MFA, the workflow is the typical onboarding with username/pass. I could not find any good documentation around this either.  I also tried explicitly putting a `<AmplifySelectMfaType>` component as a child of `<AmplifySignIn>` but it didn't do anything.

The setup is pretty simple, at the top level we display the app if a Cognito user is found, otherwise display the `AmplifyAuthenticator` to login. We don't allow users to sign themselves up to our app, so a user definition exists in Cognito when they first login.

app.component.tsx

```
import {
  AmplifyAuthenticator,
  AmplifySignIn,
  AmplifySelectMfaType,
} from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

const RoutedApp = () => {
  const { cognitoUser } = useSession();

  if (!cognitoUser) {
    return (
      <Router>
        <AmplifyAuthenticator>
          <AmplifySignIn
            headerText="Sign in"
            slot="sign-in"
            hideSignUp
            color={Colors.BRANDEIS_BLUE}
            usernameAlias="email"
            formFields={[
              {
                type: 'email',
                label: 'Email Address',
                placeholder: 'Enter your email address',
                required: true,
                disabled: true,
                value: cognito.email,
              },
              {
                type: 'password',
                label: 'Password',
                placeholder: 'Enter your password',
                required: true,
              },
            ]}
          >
            <AmplifySelectMfaType MFATypes={{ SMS: false, TOTP: true, Optional: true }} />
          </AmplifySignIn>
        </AmplifyAuthenticator>
      </Router>
    );
  }
  return <TopApplicationComponent />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **SelectMFAType** UI Component, which is provided with **aws-amplify-react** package

Refer this documentation for MFA Types

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/mfa/q/platform/js#allow-users-to-select-mfa-type